# CPU percentage using by JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jmx

I want to monitor ""Jboss 7 as"" CPU usage usage percentage, can I do this using JMX? When I write this function, I get the CPU time, not CPU percentage...

```
public String getCpuUsage(){
    try {
        Method m=op.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessCpuTime");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object value=null;
        value=m.invoke(op);
        return value+"";
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to calculate the JBoss CPU percentage?

Answer (score 0):

The process cpu time is the total number of nanoseconds of CPU used by your process since it started. So to get the percentage, you will need 2 additional pieces of information:

1. The number of CPUs. This is available from [OperatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getAvailableProcessors%28%29), or [Runtime.availableProcessors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29).
2. The corresponding wall clock time that has elapsed during the time that the process cpu time accumulated, which is best done using [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) since it supplies the same "unit" as the process cpu time.

The best way to implement Item #2 above is to periodically poll for process cpu time on a regular period and after the first poll, the elapsed wall-clock time will be the current *System.nanoTime()* minus the same collected in the prior polling period.

So now you have:

- The elapsed wall clock time (this period's time, minus last period's time)  Call this **X**
- The elapsed process cpu time (this period's time, minus last period's time) Call this **Y**
- The number of CPUs.  Call this **C**

The percent utilization will be  **Y / (X x C) * 100**

Here's a quick and dirty groovy script that demonstrates this:

```
import java.lang.management.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

osx = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
cores = osx.getAvailableProcessors();

// Factorial to keep the process busy so we can see some actual activity
factorial = { n ->
    int fact = 1;
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= n) {
        i++;
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}


long elapsedTime = -1, startTime = -1;
long elapsedCpu = -1, startCpu = -1;;

for(i in 0..20) {
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    startCpu = osx.getProcessCpuTime();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(cores);
    for(x in 1..cores) {
        Thread.startDaemon() {
            factorial(1000000);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
    latch.await();
    elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
    elapsedCpu = osx.getProcessCpuTime()-startCpu;
    percUsage = (elapsedCpu / (elapsedTime* cores)) *100;
    println "Percent Usage:$percUsage %";
}
```

The output:

```
Percent Usage:51.5167066100 %
Percent Usage:53.5206121100 %
Percent Usage:55.3874037900 %
Percent Usage:59.8187255600 %
Percent Usage:60.0488511300 %
Percent Usage:68.3172332900 %
Percent Usage:45.0529180000 %
Percent Usage:58.3662459200 %
Percent Usage:62.6933609700 %
Percent Usage:60.1530673000 %
Percent Usage:69.0448532600 %
Percent Usage:52.0072152200 %
Percent Usage:57.1837311400 %
Percent Usage:65.8311579500 %
Percent Usage:66.3076807600 %
Percent Usage:69.8803721800 %
Percent Usage:28.5111361300 %
Percent Usage:40.1093035100 %
Percent Usage:60.9499459700 %
Percent Usage:68.7113809300 %
Percent Usage:71.8252480400 %
```

You should probably round better than I did.